# 'object%20Object' Being Appended instead of parameters.

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript

I am attempting to make a call to the server using promises. When trying to add my parameters, it comes out as 'object%20Object'

Here is the call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private baseUserUrl = 'api/User/'

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getUsers(currentPage: number): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUserUrl + 'GetUsers?currentPage=' + currentPage)
            .map(resp => resp.json() as User[])
            .toPromise()
    }




}
```

Comment: use toString().

Comment: I think you're passing an object instead of number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally passing an object into the method, so I wasn't accessing the property, I was accessing the object. I fixed that and removed the object and passed a property.